# Files not found in solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, warnings

Trying checkin my changes to TFS I get policy warning "some files were not found in current solution and cannot be analyzed".

[image: policy warning screenshot]

Double-clicking on the message I get the prompt "The following files were not found to be a part of any project in currently loaded solution. Source Analysis cannot be performed."

[image: prompt screenshot]

That modal window is not resizable and not scrollable so I cannot even define what files exactly it says about.

Does anybody know what may be wrong with the project? How can I fix it?

Some details.
I've made significant changes in the solution structure since my last checkin, particularly I've deleted two project and moved files of one to another.

Comment: Are these just not 'orphan' files, that you are checking in, I'm assuming your policy is that CA must be performed but the files in your pending changes are not part of the solution? can you expand on what the Check-in policy is that is throwing the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok

you have a Code Analysis policy set against your source control. to find out why, you would need to speak to your TFS Admin, who hopefully will explain the checkin policy.

[image: Code Analysis Check-in policy]

To solve your problem, look through your pending changes and exclude any files that are not part of the current solution, as that is why you are not allowed to check-in. They may be files that you have haging around in your workspace, or they maybe files that you have worked on, but due to that policy being set, you can only check in files that are part of the current solution.